# Containerized applications with docker swarm on GCP

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, docker-swarm

I have a project to containerize **several applications** (*Gitlab, Jenkins, Wordpress, Python Flask app*...). Currently each application runs on a Compute Engine VM **each** at GCP. My goal would be to move everything to a cluster (*Swarm or Kubernetes*).

However I have different questions about Docker Swarm on Google Cloud Platform:

- How can I expose my Python application on the outside (*HTTP load balancer*) as well as the other applications only available in my **private VPC** ?
- From what I've seen on the internet, I have the impression that docker swarm is very little used. Should I go for a kubernetes cluster instead ? (*I have good knowledge of Docker/Kubernetes*)
- It is difficult to find information about Docker Swarm in cloud providers. What would be an **architecture with Docker Swarm on GCP**?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd create a template and from that an instance group for all VM, which shall host the Docker swarm. And a separate instance or instance group for said internal purposes - so that there is a strict separation, which can then be used to route the internal & external traffic accordingly (this would apply in any case). [Google Kubernetes Engine](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine) is about the same as such an instance group, but Google managed infrastructure. See the [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/hello-app), there's not much difference - except that it better integrates with `gcloud` & `kubectl`. While there is no requirement to want or need to maintain the underlying infrastructure, GKE is probably less effort.

What you are basically asking is:

- [Kubernetes vs. Docker Swarm: What’s the Difference?](https://thenewstack.io/kubernetes-vs-docker-swarm-whats-the-difference)
- [Docker Swarm vs Kubernetes: A Helpful Guide for Picking One](https://stackify.com/docker-swarm-vs-kubernetes-a-helpful-guide-for-picking-one/)
- [Kubernetes vs. Docker: What Does it Really Mean?](https://www.sumologic.com/blog/kubernetes-vs-docker/)
- [Docker Swarm vs. Kubernetes: A Comparison](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/blog/docker-swarm-vs-kubernetes-a-comparison)
- [Kubernetes vs Docker Swarm](https://platform9.com/blog/kubernetes-docker-swarm-compared/)